# Having issues with CSS animation on add/remove class

Tags: css, css-transitions

I've my DOM structure like

```
<div class="content" data-type="card">
    <i class="expand"></i>
    <div class="article">
        A: This is the main article
    </div>
</div>
```

I've my css animations as

```
.fullscreen {
    z-index: 9999; position: fixed;
    -webkit-animation: fs-expandHorizontal 300ms cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.105, 0.445, 0.830) 1 forwards,
                    fs-expandVertical 120ms cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.105, 0.445, 0.830) 1 forwards;
}


    @-webkit-keyframes fs-expandHorizontal {
        0% { width: 940px; left: 50%; margin-left: -470px; }
        100% { width: 100%; left: 0; margin-left: 0px; }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes fs-expandVertical {
        0% { height: 560px; }
        100% { height: 100vh; top: 0; }
    }

.restore {
    z-index: 9999; position: fixed;
    -webkit-animation: fs-contractVertical 300ms cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.105, 0.445, 0.830) 1 forwards,
                        fs-contractHorizontal 120ms cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.105, 0.445, 0.830) 1 forwards;
 }


    @-webkit-keyframes fs-contractHorizontal {
        0% { width: 100%; left: 0; margin-left: 0px; }
        100% { width: 940px; left: 50%; margin-left: -470px; }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes fs-contractVertical {
        0% { height: 100vh; top: 0; }
        100% { height: 560px; top: 60px;}
    }
```

On my HTML element, if I add `.fullscreen` class, it works as intended (the div animates and expands). However, When I remove `.fullscreen` and add `.restore` class, there's no animation at all.

Any idea where am I doing wrong?

`UPDATE:`
I copied only the basic codes and created a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/cbfgbphf/5/ and it seems to be working fine.

So I've 2 CSS files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="static/css/media-style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/style.css">
```

From the CSS codes I've posted above, the following is in the `style.css` and

```
.fullscreen {
    z-index: 9999; position: fixed;
    -webkit-animation: fs-expandHorizontal 300ms cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.105, 0.445, 0.830) 1 forwards,
                        fs-expandVertical 120ms cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.105, 0.445, 0.830) 1 forwards;
}


.restore {
    -webkit-animation: fs-contractVertical 120ms cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.105, 0.445, 0.830) 1 forwards,
                        fs-contractHorizontal 300ms cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.105, 0.445, 0.830) 1 forwards;
}
```

This part is in the `media-style.css`

```
@media (min-width: 1280px) and (max-width: 1440px) {
    .content {
        width: 940px; height: 560px; 
    }


    @-webkit-keyframes fs-expandHorizontal {
        0% { width: 940px; left: 50%; margin-left: -470px; }
        100% { width: 100%; left: 0; margin-left: 0px; }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes fs-expandVertical {
        0% { height: 560px; }
        100% { height: 100vh; top: 0; }
    }



    @-webkit-keyframes fs-contractHorizontal {
        0% { width: 100%; left: 0; margin-left: 0px; }
        100% { width: 940px; left: 50%; margin-left: -470px; }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes fs-contractVertical {
        0% { height: 100vh; top: 0; }
        100% { height: 560px; top: 60px;}
    }


}
```

If I put the above part in the `style.css` file together, then it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Could you make working code snippet with Javascript code also (http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Not everybody uses webkit browsers. You should also use the standard properties.